# Symfony 3 deploying app via ftp error

Tags: php, deployment, ftp, symfony

I need to upload my symfony 3 project online, but I have only access to ftp. So I did all necessary steps I found:

1. composer update
2. Clear the cache for production: `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`
3. Upload all app folder on server

After I open my website I got the following error:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/nfsmnt/hosting2_1/a/8/a87b3594-7cfe-459e-ad62-286d2dba2c54/zorbfutbal.sk/web/var..\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/php56/lib/php') in
>   /nfsmnt/hosting2_1/a/8/a87b3594-7cfe-459e-ad62-286d2dba2c54/zorbfutbal.sk/web/var/bootstrap.php.cache on line 1780

I checked the file and I have it there and also set all permissions.
What is confusing me is that path from error before my actual domain name.

> "/nfsmnt/hosting2_1/a/8/a87b3594-7cfe-459e-ad62-286d2dba2c54/"
>   I dont know  where it comed from and how to fix it.
>   Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely sure you set the file permissions correctly like indicated here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd

The message you posted seems to point to something like that.
Also run:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

just to check that you've met all the other requirements.